# Overlapping Edges when using visjs-network

Tags: vis.js

I want to visualize relations via vis-network and the tool is absolutely great.
Only one setting I can't find.
Here I have a sample output:

[current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDt95.png)

If I move the boxes manually a little bit to the left and to the right with the mouse I get this result:

[expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TASkH.png)

Basically I avoid overlapping edges.
How can I instruct vis-network to render the data without overlapping edges?
It doesn't have to look exactly like in my result, the main thing is that the overlaps are gone. If it is not possible to avoid the overlaps completely due to the data, the number of overlaps should be minimized.

My settings:

```
var options = {
  "physics": {
    "enabled": false,
    "solver": "hierarchicalRepulsion"
  },
  "layout": {
    "hierarchical": {
      "enabled": true,
      "nodeSpacing": 290,
      "sortMethod": "directed",
      "direction": "DU",
      "shakeTowards": "leaves"
    }
  },
  "nodes": {
    "shape": "box"
  },
  "edges": {
    "width": 3,
    "smooth": {
      "enabled": false,
      "type": "horizontal",
      "roundness": 0.5,
      "forceDirection": false
    }
  }
};
```

Here I put it in a js-fiddle for you to try out and tweak the options yourself:
https://jsfiddle.net/qwpxa1cj/7

If it does not work with vis-network settings Are there alternatives to make it work? E.g. by re-sorting the data array?

Who has an idea how to get an overlap-free result?

Many greetings,
Tim

Comment: Long story short, you can't, not reliably at least. You can track the progress at https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/84.